# How to add to arrays such that matching elements become their own arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I feel like there is quick way to do this with Numpy but I can't seem to find the function for it.

I need to take three arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [1,2,3]

Z = np.somefunction(a,b,c)
print Z

([1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3])
```

Comment: Are the elements unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.dstack` :

```
>>> np.dstack((a,b,c))
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
```

Also as says @ Warren Weckesser said in comment since `np.dstack` returns a 3d array as a better way you can use following way :

```
>>> np.array((a, b, c)).T
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Do you realize that the result of the `dstack` call is a *3-dimensional* array, with shape (1, 3, 3)?  `np.column_stack((a,b,c))`, `np.vstack((a, b, c)).T` or `np.array((a, b, c)).T` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for the comment. I will use one of those instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the input arrays are all 1-d, you can use `np.column_stack`:

```
In [13]: np.column_stack((a,b,c))
Out[13]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `zip(a, b, c)`. Simple as that, no Numpy needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just transpose the matrix using standard python functions, like `zip` which you can wrap in an array:

```
numpy.array(zip(*(a, b, c))) # zip unpacks the matrix, tranposes it, and becomes an array
```